# Django create empty formset with fixed number of form

Tags: django, forms, formset

I would like to create an empty formset with fixed number ( more than 1)
I am not sure is it possible to do it in views.py. I saw many methods using jquery to create a new form.

here is my code to create a new form, however the number of form is only one.

```
MyStuffSet = modelformset_factory( MyStuff )

formset =  MyStuffSet( queryset = MyStuff.objects.none() )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `extra` parameter . like :

```
MyStuffSet = modelformset_factory(MyStuff, extra=3)
```

OR Condition based :

```
MyStuffSet = modelformset_factory(MyStuff, extra=1 if request.POST.has_key('any_key') else 0)
```